# mongorestore on a cluster with secondary node instead of primary

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I am familiar with mongodump and mongorestore commands. I am not clear if mongorestore can be run on secondary. When I run it, I see restore happening successfully. But say mongorestore for db "mydb" is done on secondary will it always take priority even if the node is not primary?

In short, doing a mongorestore on secondary is officially going to work?

Comment: It's not possible to restore to a secondary. Please post the procedure that you did so we know more about the state of your deployment.

Comment: no special procedure. I went to secondary node and did "mongorestore --drop --archive "

Comment: What do you mean by "went to secondary node"? `mongorestore` should fail with `no reachable servers`. What MongoDB version are you using? What is the output of `rs.status()`?

Comment: I can paste the output but do you want to see the whole JSON of rs. status? I have a 3 node Mongo cluster. When I say I went to secondary, I went to the docker container running mongodb as secondary node and ran the mongorestore and it worked. But is that officially the right way? I am not sure. I am using 3.4

Comment: The whole output would help, since it allows us to determine whether `mongorestore` is connecting to the right `mongod`. It is entirely possible that `mongorestore` is connecting to the primary even though it's run from a secondary container.

Comment: Here is the link to the output of ``rs.status()`` that I ran on the secondary
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ex1c6fr71hw2hvq/secondaryOutput.txt?dl=0

Comment: There's nothing wrong as far as I can tell with your deployment. When you done `mongorestore` on the secondary, can you then find the restored collection on that secondary, but not on the primary?

Comment: i can find it on the primary and it is synced perfectly. But I do not know that this is guaranteed always. That is where the whole dilemma and hence the reason to pose this Q on stackoverflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157417/discussion-between-kevin-adistambha-and-curiousengineer).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify --host=node1,node2,node3 etc to run mongorestore from a secondary.

```
mongorestore --help
...
connection options:
  -h, --host=<hostname>                                     mongodb host to connect to (setname/host1,host2 for replica sets)
```